# Showing a set is an ideal in a ring of real-valued functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory, ideals, real-numbers

If $F$ is a ring of all real-valued functions defined on $\mathbb{R}$, is  $S = \{f ∈ F | f(0) = 1\}$ an ideal?

What I'm thinking is $(f+g)(0) = f(0)+g(0) = 1+1 = 2$ 
and hence $f + g$ is in $S$? Is that a real-valued function? Also, the additive inverse of $f$ is $−f$ and we have
$(−f)(0) = −f(0) = −1$ and hence $−f$ is in $S$? Again not sure if it's a real-valued function. Finally, suppose that $h ∈ F$. Then we have
$(hf)(0) = h(0)·f(0) = h(0)·1 = 1$ and hence $hf$ is in the set $S$. I think $F$ is a commutative ring, so we have $fh = hf$ and hence $fh$
is in $S$? I'm not sure if any of these are actually in $S$ however, I feel like I need to establish a constant function or something in the beginning for this to make sense though

Also what if $\{f ∈ F | f$ is continuous$\}$

Comment: If $(f+g)(0)=2$ how can you say $f+g \in S$?

Comment: i'm not sure if it is, i'm quite lost on this problem

Comment: It seems to me that you're confused about the definitions of everything here.  Before trying to understand if this is an ideal, figure out what all your objects are.  In other words, start at the beginning, and define a real-valued function, addition for real-valued functions, the set being studied, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S is not an ideal.  It isn't closed under addition.

To boot, take $h\in F$ such that $h(0)\neq1$.  Then $(hf)(0)=h(0)\cdot f(0)=h(0)\cdot 1=h(0)\neq1$.  Thus $hf\not\in S$, violating the condition to be an ideal.

$\{f\in F\mid f \text{ is continuous}\}$ is a subring, but not closed under multiplication on the left, hence is also not an ideal.  That is, consider the constant function,  $f(x)=1\,,\forall x$.  And any discontinuous function $g$.  Then $gf=g$ is discontinuous.   Hence again,  the condition for an ideal is not met.